# ¿Cómo agregar correctamente la variable devuelta como argumento a las Opciones() de selenium en este programa de python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, selenium, selenium-webdriver, depuración

Este programa le solicita al usuario el `Profile Path` de su navegador de Chrome, para luego añadir esa ruta como un argumento a las opciones de Selenium en la declaración `opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+f"r'{x}'")`:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk #for user inputs
from tkinter import messagebox #for warning messages 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400') #resolution
root.title("Bulkdozer") #Name of this program
root.attributes('-topmost', True) #keep the program's window top-most

x = ""
def submit_profile_path():
    if len(profile_path.get()) == 0: #check if the user didn't type anything and pressed the button 
        messagebox.showerror(message="You didn't provide any input, try again", title="NULL Input")
    elif len(profile_path.get()) > 0:
        if r'\Google\Chrome\User Data' in profile_path.get(): #check if the path provided by the user is a valid one
            if profile_path.get().split("User Data\\",1)[1] != "": #now check if at the end of that path exist an actual profile folder
                user_data.pack_forget() #hide the user_data button
                data_input.pack_forget() #hide the data_input
                profile_path_label.pack_forget() #hide the profile_path_label
                open_browser.pack() #show the open_browser button
                global x
                x = profile_path.get()
                return x
                
            else: #inform the user that he must provide the profile path containing the corresponding profile folder
                messagebox.showwarning(message="You forgot to add the PROFILE FOLDER in the profile path, try again", title="Profile Folder Missing")
                data_input.delete(0, tk.END)        
                
        else: #inform the user that he must provide a valid profile path
            messagebox.showwarning(message="The path provided does not seem to be the right one, try again", title="Invalid Profile PATH")
            data_input.delete(0, tk.END)
            
# BUTTON FOR PROVIDING THE PROFILE PATH OF CHROME BROWSER #
profile_path = tk.StringVar() #This variable will be used for storing the profile path string passed by the user
signin = ttk.Frame(root) #create a container for the profile_path variable
signin.pack(padx=55, pady=20, fill='x', expand=True) #define the dimensional measurement and location for this container
profile_path_label = ttk.Label(signin, text="Introduce YOUR profile path:") #create a label for the profile_path variable
profile_path_label.pack(fill='x', expand=True) #add the label
data_input = ttk.Entry(signin, textvariable=profile_path) #create an entry for the profile_path variable
data_input.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
data_input.focus()
user_data = tk.Button(root, width=20,  text="Submit User Data", command=submit_profile_path) #executes the function when clicked
user_data.place(x=60, y=40, width=100, height=30) #define the dimensional measurement and location for this button
user_data.pack() #Apply The Pack geometry manager to this button for using its functions later on


opt = Options() #selenium options
opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+f"r'{x}'") #PATH profile
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Profile to use
s = Service('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

########################     BUTTON ZONE     #############################

def open_chrome_profile():
    #webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://opensea.io/asset/create') #open a new tab using user's default browser
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
    driver.get('https://opensea.io/login?referrer=%2Faccount')

# BUTTON FOR OPENING A CHROME DRIVER WITH THE OPTIONS PASSED #

open_browser = tk.Button(root, width=20,  text="Open OpenSea Tab", command=open_chrome_profile) #executes the function when clicked
open_browser.place(width=100, height=30) #define the dimensional measurement and location for this button
open_browser.pack() #Apply The Pack geometry manager to this button for using its functions later on
open_browser.pack_forget() #initialize this button hidden

######################     BUTTON ZONE END     ###########################
root.mainloop()
```

Sin embargo, después de compilar este programa y haber presionado el botón de `open_browser` se generó el siguiente error:

> Google Chrome no puede leer ni agregar datos al directorio de datos: r''

Yo pensé que al asignar el valor de `profile_path.get()` a la variable global `x` y retornándola, el programa podría efectivamente llamar la variable `x` actualizada en `opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir="+f"r'{x}'")` para luego ejecutar un driver de Chrome con los correspondientes datos de usuario, pero no fue así.

También debo reconocer que no estoy seguro de sí esta declaración `f"r'{x}'"` está en realidad haciendo lo que yo creo que está haciendo, entonces hice este post para solicitar retroalimentación sobre como el profile path proveído por el usuario en este programa podría efectivamente ser añadido como un argumento a las opciones de Selenium después de ejecutar `submit_profile_path()`.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de variable es `profile_path` y cuál es el de su función `get`?

Answer (score 1):

Tu confusión está en cuándo usar la `r`.

`r` y `f` son prefijos para literales de string (es decir, indicas el contenido de un string en el código). Unos ejemplos:

```
 "Hola"
 'Literal'
```

La [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) de literales dice:

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters.

Los literales de string y byte opcionalmente pueden ser antecedidos por una letra `r` o `R`. Dichos literales se llaman `raw strings` y tratan las barras invertidas como carácteres literales.

Cuando el string lo lees de algún archivo o lo tiene que ingresar el usuario, no necesitas la `r` porque no se trata de un literal. Lo mismo aplica para los strings con formato (`f` o `F` de prefijo).

Dicho esto, considera esta manera de indicar el parámetro:

```
fr'--user-data-dir="{x}"'
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, creo que esa declaración que mencionas puede ser la solución, sin embargo, al probarla en el código de arriba, obtuve el siguiente error: 
```selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at "" is still attached to a running Chrome or Chromium process``` lo que significa que la variable ```x``` no parece estar retornando correctamente el path que debería ```C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default```, qué sugerencia me puedes dar?

Comment: Te hice un comentario con algunas preguntas porque pensé que tal vez podría haber algo más que impida el correcto funcionamiento del programa. También puedes debugear el código y ver que pasa con la variable `x`.